# Analog audio amplifier schematic

Tags: amplifier, analog, audio

I am a complete noob in electronics and I have to design an analog audio amplifier (schematic in Capture CIS and calculus) for my CAD's semester project with the given input data:

```
Voltage Gain (Avi): 600u
Bandwidth: [8192; 16384] Hz
Voltage Range (A1,A2): [4;9] V
Load Resistance (R0): 35 Ohm
```

Since I am not really interested in electronics (not passionate about it either) and the teacher didn't really help us, I find it hard to do it.

I tried this:
[image: Figure 1. Trashy circuit]

Copy pasted from the documentation, I know it's blurry, but it doesn't work anyway.
Can somebody please give me some indications (simple, straight to subj., what components should I use and how) or maybe a schematic if you have one somewhere? I really want to get rid of this subject.

Comment: `the documentation` What material can *the teacher* expect you to work from?

Comment: Is this the circuit you have to use? It's a simple Class A amplifier and the web is full of examples and tutorials. Like [this one](https://learnabout-electronics.org/Downloads/amplifiers-module-02.pdf)

Comment: He thinks that we know all about circuits and electronics from other subjects, pretending that we passed all those exams. Anyway, everyone is confused in his class. All of our projects are a mess.

Comment: Nope. That image is the first version of my schematic. Apparently, the teacher told me that it doesn't respect the given input data.

Comment: So I only have to draw the schematic in Capture CIS, do the calculus, make a documentation and a .ppt . No hardware or physical implementation

Answer (score 2):

Your schematic had its parts too far apart making the text too small. I enlarged and cropped it.
The transistor is biased wrongly causing the emitter signal to hit against the collector signal.
I corrected the biasing.
The two 35 ohm loads are severely overloading the much higher collector resistor which reduces the gain down to almost nuthin.

[image: transistor 1]
[image: transistor 2]

Comment: I don't think this deserved a downvote, as it just showed a simulation of the OP's circuit and explanation of why it does not meet the specs. It would then be up to the OP to do the work to analyze and modify appropriately. And @Finbarr's link provides all the info needed.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I won't simply copy and paste from here. I just needed some guidance and I will take everything into consideration and try to figure out the task, alone. I'll be right back

Answer (score -1):

After changing the load to 350 ohms parallel with 35 ohm (why two resistors?) the 3k ohms collector resistor is still severely overloaded and the biasing is still wrong.

Since it is a class-A heater, I reduced all the resistances to make it work.
I think your teacher wanted a class-AB push-pull power amplifier.

[image: transistor 3]

Comment: This should not be a free coursework making service. OP might even get caught that someone made the project for him, and plagiarism is a serious academic misconduct.

Comment: I agree. It should be up to the OP to take the help he has been offered and run with that. There must be a reason why this project was assigned.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I won't simply copy what is here. I just needed some push/help. Currently I am trying to figure out things